# Timestamp as all zeroes on insert/update on duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following queries running in a php script, and they work perfectly as far as inserting the selected values. But the first time it runs, the timestamp (time_of_report field)has the correct date with 00:00:00 as the time. When I run it again, the time is then correct.

I'm assuming it might have something to do with my update/duplicate syntax. And my Time_of_report field is indeed a timestamp data type.

Is there any obvious reason why it has to run twice to update the timestamp correctly?

```
$data = mysqli_query($conn,
"SELECT 
      c.extension
      , sum(Duration) AS Total_Talk_Time_seconds
      , round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) AS Total_Talk_Time_minutes
      , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) AS Total_Outbound
      , sum( case when(legtype1 = 1 and duration > 60) then 1 else 0 end) AS Credit_for_outbound
      , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0) and ANSWERED = 1) AS Total_Inbound
      , sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) AS Total_Missed
      , SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound calls
        SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 2, 1, 0) AND ANSWERED = 1) +  -- inbound calls
        SUM(IF(Answered = 1, 0, 1))  AS Total_Calls     
      , NOW() AS Time_of_report
      , curdate() AS Date_of_report
FROM cdrdb.session a
    INNER JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b 
      ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
    INNER join cdrdb.mxuser c 
      ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
    WHERE b.ts >= curdate()
    AND c.extension IN (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)
    group by c.extension")  or die(mysqli_error( $conn));


//statement 1, this inserts and updates upon duplicates into the 
 ambition.ambitionphone table which is our main table for all ambition 
metric data.
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn2, 
"INSERT into ambition.ambitionphone
      (Extension,
      Total_Talk_Time_seconds, 
      Total_Talk_Time_minutes,
      Total_Outbound,
      Credit_for_outbound, 
      Total_Inbound,
      Missed_Calls, 
      Total_Calls, 
      Date_of_report,
      Time_of_report )
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
ON duplicate key 
update
      Total_Talk_Time_seconds = values(Total_Talk_Time_seconds),
      Total_Talk_Time_minutes = values(Total_Talk_Time_minutes),
      Total_Inbound = values(Total_Inbound),
      Total_Outbound = values(Total_Outbound),
      Credit_for_outbound = values(Credit_for_outbound),
      Missed_Calls = values(Missed_Calls),
      Total_Calls = values(Total_Calls),
      Time_of_report = NOW()
") or die(mysqli_error( $conn2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. First time you set Time_of_report from your php value (you didn't show what exactly you set after `mysqli_prepare`). And whjen you update that, you set Time_of_report as `NOW()`.

I would recommend to set default value for Time_of_report as `NOW()` also:

```
ALTER TABLE ambition.ambitionphone MODIFY COLUMN Time_of_report datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW();
```

Then you should remove field `Time_of_report` from your insert code at all.

Comment: Ok, I set my default value. But do you mean remove Time_of_report from the select, insert and update statements? So it shouldn't even exist in the PHP?

Comment: No, I mean remove it only from all inserts.